# How do I convert an R character vector to a C character pointer?

Tags: c, r

I'm trying to pass a character vector from R to C and reference it through a C character pointer. However, I don't know which type conversion macro to use. Below is a small test illustrating my problem.

File test.c:

```
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP test(SEXP chars)
{
   char *s;

   s = CHAR(chars);
   return R_NilValue;
}
```

File test.R:

```
dyn.load("test.so")

chars <- c("A", "B")

.Call("test", chars)
```

Output from R:

```
> source("test.R")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  CHAR() can only be applied to a 'CHARSXP', not a 'character'
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string in *chars* can be retrieved by getting each character through the pointer `CHAR(STRING_ELT(chars, i))`, where 0 <= *i* < length(chars), and storing it in `s[i]`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP test(SEXP chars)
{
   int n, i;
   char *s;

   n = length(chars);
   s = malloc(n + 1);
   if (s != NULL) {
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         s[i] = CHAR(STRING_ELT(chars, i));
      }
      s[n] = '\0';
   } else {
      /*handle malloc failure*/
   }
   return R_NilValue;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Character vectors are `STRSXP`.  Each individual element is `CHARSXP`, so you need something like (untested):

```
const char *s;
s = CHAR(STRING_ELT(chars, 0));
```

See the [Handling Character Data section of *Writing R Extensions*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Handling-character-data).  Dirk will be along shortly to tell you how this all will be easier if you just use C++ and Rcpp. :)

Comment: The expression `CHAR(STRING_ELT(chars, 0))` gives me a pointer to the first character only (the character after is '\0'). To get all the characters it turns out I need to iterate through the characters (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

As per Josh's request:

```
R> pickString <- cppFunction('std::string pickString(std::vector<std::string> invec, int pos) { return invec[pos]; } ')
R> pickString(c("The", "quick", "brown", "fox"), 1)
[1] "quick"
R>
```

C vectors are zero-offset, so 1 picks the second element.

Comment: Or even more succinctly: `cppFunction('String pickString(CharacterVector invec, int pos) { return invec[pos]; } ')`  (cppFunction does the assignment for you)

Comment: Yes, but the OP is a C programmer so I figured I'd stay with standard types and hide ours.