# Converting an SEXP from R into a vector of strings in C++

Tags: c++, r, string

I am trying to pass a character vector (i.e. vector of strings) from R to C/C++ for sorting and other purposes. When using Rcpp, this can easily be done with the following code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector sort(CharacterVector x) {

  std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
  return x;
}
```

However, as this is my only planned use of C++ in this package, it hardly seems worthwhile to introduce the dependency on Rcpp. Doing the same without it isn't so easy. Integers are easy enough:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
SEXP sort(SEXP x) {
  int* xx = INTEGER(x);
  std::sort(xx, xx+LENGTH(x));
  return(x);
}
```

But there isn't `std::vector<string>` or `char**` equivalent to `INTEGER()`.

How can I emulate the same code without introducing the dependency to Rcpp?

There are questions on here that discuss how to use `CHAR(STRING_ELT())` to convert a single string, but it is not clear how to convert into an array/vector of strings.

Comment: Exactly why do think _it hardly seems worthwhile to introduce the dependency on Rcpp_ when it, even according to you, already provides a working answer?  Asking for a friend...

Comment: Also, allow me to remove the tag for Rcpp  as you are asking for non-Rcpp answer.

Comment: My package is 22kB.  Rcpp is 3MB.  Also, some people (such as my own company) have difficulty importing dependencies.  That's all a substantial overhead for one function.

Comment: i) You get your package as a binary, pre-built, with a dynamic library dependency. ii) Chances are you already have Rcpp via other Depends: iii) Rcpp may be 3mb but R alone is dozens times that. File size in mb rarely matters in 2015.  Anyway, your self-imposed hardship, and thanks for sharing.

Comment: The code will be simpler and more maintenable if  you use Rcpp but if you really don't wnat to then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961832/how-do-i-convert-an-r-character-vector-to-a-c-character-pointer

Comment: @Gabor: OP wants a vector of strings.  But I concur with the recommendation...

Comment: Is it even worth introducing the dependency on a C compiler? How much faster is that C++ sort over R's sort? Is it that critical to your application? Have you profiled your code in pure R to see where the bottleneck is? Sure it depends on what your mysterious "other purposes" are, but you should probably code it in R first and then you have a base for testing.

Comment: @Spacedman:  Sort is just one example.  However, see Martin's answer below: for large string vectors, there is a 10-20x speedup in C++ over R.  This is consistent with my own tests.

Comment: @Craig: Yes, you generally want C++ for lots of data, large data or both. Which is why you may want to rethink your apparent disliking of Rcpp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`STRING_PTR()` is analogous to `INTEGER()`. It returns a `SEXP *`. Dereferencing the value is the SEXP of the first element of the R character vector; `STRING_PTR(x)[0]` is the same as `STRING_ELT(x, 0)`. The SEXP is itself a pointer to a data structure that contains a `const char *` to the actual characters of the first element of the character vector; this pointer might be accessed by `CHAR(STRING_PTR(x)[i])`. The various macros are defined in `file.path(R.home("include"), "Rinternals.h")`

The default `std::sort(STRING_PTR(x), STRING_PTR(x) + LENGTH(x))` compares the de-referenced values of the arguments, i.e., compares the pointer addresses of the elements -- `STRING_PTR(x)[i] < STRING_PTR(x)[j]`. What you want is to compare the actual null-terminated C strings, `strcmp(CHAR(STRING_PTR(x)[i]), CHAR(STRING_PTR(x)[j]))`. Your original `std::sort(x.begin(), x.end())` does not actually  return sorted strings (I think the Rcpp way of doing the sort is `x.sort()`).

You need a custom comparator that takes SEXP, extracts the `const char *` (via the `CHAR()` macro), and compares these. Here's the comparator

```
struct CMP_CHAR {
    bool operator()(SEXP x, SEXP y) {
        return strcmp(CHAR(x), CHAR(y)) < 0;
    }
} cmp_char;
```

and the implementation

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP sortcpp0(SEXP x) {
    std::sort(STRING_PTR(x), STRING_PTR(x) + LENGTH(x), cmp_char);
    return x;
}
```

(I use Rcpp in the example above to make it easy to continue to use `sourceCpp()`, but this could be removed and the code compiled with `R CMD SHLIB` or used in a package without depending on Rcpp).

Note though that this is a VERY BAD idea, because the direct manipulation of an object passed from R without copying breaks the illusion of copy-on-change and introduces action at a distance -- in the below, `x` *and* `y` are changed even though only `x` is sorted.

```
> n = 10; set.seed(123); x = y = sample(as.character(1:n))
> sortcpp0(x); y
 [1] "1"  "10" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" 
 [1] "1"  "10" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"
```

I believe that the naive Rcpp implementation

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector sortRcpp2(CharacterVector x) {
    return x.sort();
}
```

also suffers from this -- the input argument needs to be duplicated before sorting. The solution is simple -- duplicate (and PROTECT! even though not technically needed in the present example) the incoming argument.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP sortcpp(SEXP x) {
    x = PROTECT(Rf_duplicate(x));
    std::sort(STRING_PTR(x), STRING_PTR(x) + LENGTH(x), cmp_char);
    UNPROTECT(x);
    return x;
}
```

with the expected behavior

```
> n = 10; set.seed(123); x = y = sample(as.character(1:n))
> sortcpp(x); y
 [1] "1"  "10" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" 
 [1] "3"  "8"  "4"  "7"  "6"  "1"  "10" "9"  "2"  "5"
```

I think there is some trivial Rcpp incantation (`Rcpp::clone()`, thanks @DirkEddelbuettel) for duplicating the argument, too, and this should be considered a required practice for any argument that is altered by the C++ code.

@Spacedman points out that R's sort is maybe ok -- it falls quickly to C, has a reasonably fast (though not fastest) sort implementation, and has lots of nice functionality built in (e.g., handling NA's, and different system locales; the latter influence sort order in very subtle ways). But there are still big gains to be had (I was surprised by this...)

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> n = 1e4; set.seed(123); x = sample(as.character(1:n))
> identical(sort(x), sortcpp(x))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(sort(x), sortcpp(x))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    sort(x) 56.061580 56.563541 57.034674 56.997618 57.667031 59.003068   100
 sortcpp(x)  3.542409  3.556655  3.610071  3.582562  3.662196  3.800319   100
```

Finally, despite the comments on the post, and the closed original post, searching StackOverflow for [[r] STRING_PTR](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+STRING_PTR) returns exactly one hit -- this answer.

Comment: I suspect the speed difference may be that R is using the collating sequence of the locale and C++ is just using ASCII.

Comment: I think you want `Rcpp::clone()` to force a distinct copy. That too is discussed in a number of places.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very thorough question/answer, this would have taken me painful hours to solve. Also thanks for helping solve the question regardless of any personal opinions about the quality/nature of the question.