# Calling a generic C library from R

Tags: r, c

I am trying to write some simple R bindings for a C library. It is tdjson and many languages can interface with it directly.

I compiled the source for the library and got a fully working built (libtdjson.so) and tested it with python.

Here is a reference implementation with python using the exact same library:

```py
from ctypes import *
import json

# load shared library
tdjson_path = "tdlib/lib/libtdjson.so"
tdjson = CDLL(tdjson_path)

_td_execute = tdjson.td_execute
_td_execute.restype = c_char_p
_td_execute.argtypes = [c_char_p]

def td_execute(query):
    query = json.dumps(query).encode('utf-8')
    result = _td_execute(query)
    if result:
        result = json.loads(result.decode('utf-8'))
    return result

# test TDLib execute method

test_command = {'@type': 'getTextEntities', 
                'text': '@telegram /test_command https://telegram.org telegram.me', 
                '@extra': ['5', 7.0, 'a']}

td_execute(test_command)
```

When I try to interface with the library in R, I do not get any return value from the function calls. I only get a list with one item which contains the original call. Anyone knows how to that?

This is what I've tried in R:

```r
library(jsonlite)

dyn.load("tdlib/lib/libtdjson.so", type = "External")

td_execute <- function(query) {
  query <- jsonlite::toJSON(query, auto_unbox = T)
  result <- .C("td_execute", charToRaw(query))
  return(result)
}

test_command = list("@type"="getTextEntities",
                    "text"="@telegram /test_command https://telegram.org telegram.me",
                    "@extra"= c("5", 7.0, 'a'))

t <- td_execute(test_command)
rawToChar(t[[1]])
# t only contains the original JSON string
```

The only return values from the lists are basically an echo of the function call parameters.

Comment: The `.C` interface does not return a useful value, it returns values by changing its arguments, see [WRE, section 5.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran)..

Comment: Ok, I've read the documentation you linked, but what does that mean?

Comment: It means that `charToRaw(query)` is wrong. You pass a R vector of class `"character"`, in C that's a `char **`, assign the pointer in the function and on return R can access the value: `result <- .C("td_execute", charToRaw(query)); result[[1]]` is the value of the function's 1st argument.

Comment: These might be useful, [How do I convert an R character vector to a C character pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961832/how-do-i-convert-an-r-character-vector-to-a-c-character-pointer) but [don't use `malloc` in R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Memory-allocation). And [this R-Help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-March/046840.html).

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't understand. The python reference implementation sends a JSON request to the C library by converting it to a raw byte string. The library expects a  C char* datatype. I've been trying different ways of sending the JSON data to the .C() call but none worked.

I update my question to include the python reference

Comment: @Paul There is _a lot_ to cover in your question and having done so a few dozen times over the years, with or without Rcpp context, I ended up writing [a short arXiv paper on interfacing a C(++) library from R](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416).  All this is not a cake walk.  Do some reading, make some choices. You have options, and it _is_ imminently doable.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks for the link and I will give it a good read. Two thoughts on that: 1) It is really simple to interface with C from Python and many other languages, so I did not expect to hit rocket science here. 2) it is really difficult to search for solutions since the keywords are single letters `R`, `C` and google basically returns only non-relevant results

Comment: The first edition of Advanced R by Hadley Wickham had a chapter on R's C interface which you can read here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html . The second edition removed that chapter but still has info about C++.

Comment: I think the discussion derails from my original question: "How to call a C function from a generic library in R". I've shown the code that I've tried and a reference implementation to show that the external library works as expected. I do not think that the Python example is irrelevant, I've could have used PHP, Lua, Haskell, or any other language that can interface with the library as it is shipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in this case. R requires a custom compilation of the source code with R-specific header files.